# MPJPEG Expected boundary '--' not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I get the following error when streaming from a video camera.

**"[mpjpeg @ 00555000] Expected boundary '--' not found, instead found a line of n bytes"**

When debugging, the above error is written to the console multiple times a second. As a result i can only get a frame every many seconds. This prevents me to actually stream from the camera. In release mode, the problem is not there.

I'd like to solve the problem the clean way by letting ffmpeg know that stream is not **mpjpeg** but a **mjpeg** one.

I read about forcing **"-f mjpeg"** in ffmpeg.exe, but i'm not actually using ffmpeg.exe: i'm using its libraries directly.

So how do i set those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use av_find_input_format, like ffmpeg does:

```
AVInputFormat* iformat = av_find_input_format("mjpeg");

avformat_open_input(&format_context, ip_cam_http_address, iformat, &opts)
```